# Vimeo iframe embed wrapped in a link - Link not working

Tags: html, css, vimeo-player

I have a responsive embedded Vimeo video wrapped in a link. But the link doesn't work or show cursor on hover. Any ideas why?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.container a{
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.embed-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.embed-container iframe{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js' id='vimeo-js'></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <div class="embed-container">
      <div id="home-feat-player-item1" data-vimeo-initialized="true">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/622416001?h=1e51090569&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;muted=1&amp;controls=0&amp;app_id=122963" width="640" height="360"></iframe>
       </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea Error: The `frameborder` attribute on the `iframe` element is obsolete.

Error: The element `iframe` must not appear as a descendant of the `a` element.

Comment: I've removed the frameborder (this is automatically added by Vimeo). But it still doesn't work. If I understand your comment correctly you are saying that an iframe can not be a child element of a link?

Comment: The `iframe` can't be child of `a` link. :-) `<a><iframe></iframe></a>` is wrong. that's why it is not working.

Comment: For more information ( https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element ). They said _The a element can be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g., buttons or other links)._ The `iframe` is interactive content.

Comment: Given you can't have the structure exactly as you currently have it, could you describe more what the scenario is? Do you want the user to be able to interact with the iframe or is it just a way of showing a video automatically?

Comment: @AHaworth Normally It would be a case of having an image and title wrapped in an <a href> but in this case, I have a Vimeo video (rather than an image). The idea being the video is muted and auto-plays on hover. But if the user clicks the video it jumps through to the main video page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the problem however by setting the code like this, it works.

```
<div style="padding:75% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/622416001?h=1e51090569&amp;badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=122963" 
frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen 
style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" >
</iframe>
</div>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```